# Missing inbound app id header from Java ManagedVM url fetch requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I have a Java application running on App Engine's ManagedVMs. I am currently attempting to have it make a call to another module within my application. This module uses the value of the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header for security to ensure that only other modules may call that endpoint. However, this header does not get properly set in my request. I've followed the [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) instructions, including setting `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);` as instructed, but the header is still not set.

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

```
    URL url = new URL("https", hostname, "/path");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

    String value = req.getHeader("My-Header");
    if (value != null) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("My-Header", value);
    }

    int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (respCode != 200) {
        resp.sendError(respCode, "invalid response code from upstream");
        return;
    }

    // use the successful response...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using the [URLFetchService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService) directly rather than `java.net.URL`. My guess is that in a Managed VMs application you can make regular network requests (which don't have the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header set) using the url package, and you must use the URLFetchService directly in order to go through the url fetch infrastructure.